# AJAX post multiple data after file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this code that uploads a file with `$_FILES`:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function() {
    var FilesID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(FilesID);
    var data = new FormData();

    jQuery.each(jQuery("#" + FilesID)[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file-'+i, file);
    });

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'upload/index.php',
        data: data + '&picid=' + FilesID,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){

            $("#alertspan").text(data);
            document.getElementById("alertbox").style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("alertbox").style.display = 'none';},5000);
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to add POST data on top of the file upload, basically so that in addition to the uploaded file, you have `picid` equal to the variable `FileID`.

Comment: Tried `js` at Question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `data.append('picid', FilesID);` prior to calling `jQuery.ajax()`?

If you're OK with GET instead of POST, just use `'upload/index.php?picid=' + encodeURIComponent(FilesID)`